# Geometric meaning of the product of ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the partial order of quasi-coherent ideals of a scheme $X$. Actually it also carries a product which is compatible with the partial order. (This makes this partial order a commutative [quantale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantale). See [MO/26607](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26607/what-does-the-semiring-of-ideals-of-a-ring-r-tell-us-about-r) for the significance of the semiring.)

Since the partial order of quasi-coherent ideals of $X$ is anti-isomorphic to the partial order of closed subschemes of $X$, it follows that also the latter partial order has a product $*$. Hence, $A * B := V(I(A) * I(B))$. For the underlying topological spaces we have $|A * B| = |A| \cup |B|$.

**Question.** What is the geometric meaning of $A * B$? Has this construction been studied? Does it have a name? Is there any connection to classical intersection theory?

I only know that sometimes $A * A$ is called a thickening of $A$. I've already asked a similar question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69037).