# If $\sqrt{I}=I$ is an ideal of $k[T]$, $k$ an alg. closed field, and $I=\bigcap P_i$, we have that the $P_i$ are unique if $P_i$ have no inclusions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, maximal-and-prime-ideals

*This is part of **Exercise 1.2.6(2)** on page 4 of Springer's "Linear Algebraic Groups (Second Edition)". The first part is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1965167/104041).*

### The Details:

Since definitions vary:

> A *topological space* $(X,\tau)$ is a set $\tau$ of subsets of $X$, called *closed subsets*, such that
>
> - $\varnothing, X\in\tau$,
> - The intersection $$\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i$$ of any closed subsets $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ is closed, where $I$ is arbitrary, and
> - The union of finitely many closed sets is closed.

Note that $\tau$ is omitted sometimes when the context is clear.

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field.

We have that the *radical* $\sqrt{I}$ of an ideal $I$ of $S=k[T_1,\dots, T_n]$ is the ideal of all $f\in S$ with $f^m\in I$ for some $m\in\Bbb N$.

We denote by $\mathcal{V}(I)$ the set of all zeros of $I$.

Let $X\subseteq V=k^n$. Denote by $\mathcal{I}(X)\subseteq S$ the ideal of the $f\in S$ with $f(v)=0$ for all $v\in X$.

> **Hilbert's Nullstellensatz:** For any ideal $I$ of $S$, we have $$\mathcal{I}(\mathcal V(I))=\sqrt{I}.$$

On page 2, **1.2.1** reads,

> A topological space $X\neq\varnothing $ is *reducible* if it is the union of two proper closed subsets. Otherwise $X$ is *irreducible*. A subset $A\subset X$ is irreducible if it is irreducible for the induced topology. Notice that $X$ is irreducible if and only if any two nonempty open subsets of $X$ have a nonempty intersection.

On page 3, we have

> **1.2.5 Proposition:** A closed subset $X$ of $V$ is irreducible${}^\dagger$ if and only if $\mathcal I(X)$ is a prime ideal.

### The Question:

> Suppose $I=\sqrt{I}$ is an ideal of $S$ s.t. $$I=P_1\cap \dots\cap P_s$$ for prime ideals $P_i$. (This can be done for all $I$ by the previous part.) Suppose there are no inclusions among the $P_i$. Show that the $P_i$ are uniquely determined up to order.

### Thoughts:

Suppose

$$I=Q_1\cap\dots\cap Q_t$$

for prime $Q_j$. Select a $Q_r$ for some $r$. An idea suggested to me is to consider

$$Q_rI=(Q_rP_1)\cap \dots\cap(Q_rP_s);$$

however, I'm not sure where to go with this.

By **Hilbert's Nullstellensatz**, we have

$$\mathcal{I}(\mathcal V(I))=I.$$

I think we could then use **1.2.5 Proposition** somehow.

Please help :)

---

$\dagger$: . . . with respect to the [Zariski topology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology) . . .

Comment: The idea is that the ideal $P_1$ Is contained in $Q_i$ for some $ i$, and similarly $Q_i \subset P_j$ for some $j$. $P_1 \subset P_j$ implies $P_1=Q_i=P_j$ since there are not inclusions among $P_k$. What you can do for that is, supposing $P_1\nsubseteq Q_i$ for all $i$, to construct an element $f\in P_1$ such that $f\notin Q_i$ to lead to contradiction.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $Q$ is any prime ideal that contains $I$.  Then $P_1P_2\dots P_n\subseteq P_1\cap P_2\cap\dots\cap P_n= I\subseteq Q$.  Since $Q$ is prime, this implies $P_i\subseteq Q$ for some $i$.

In particular, if $Q$ is a minimal prime containing $I$, then $Q$ must be equal to $P_i$ for some $i$, i.e. the $P_i$ include all the minimal primes over $I$.  Since every prime containing $I$ contains a minimal such prime and there are no inclusions among the $P_i$, this implies the $P_i$ must be exactly the minimal primes over $I$.  So, they are uniquely determined up to order.